# possible to set a variable from a google script API call?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get an 8-digit authentication code from the Google script API, and have gotten some help on another thread, and the following was recommended. Note: userEmail is a variable for the person's email address. =)

```
var codes = AdminDirectory.VerificationCodes.list(userEmail).items.forEach(function(item){Logger.log('Code: ' + item.verificationCode)});
```

it was mentioned as part of a function.

would it be possible to just call the API and retrieve an 8-digit code directly into a var?

like:
var 8DigitCode = AdminDirectory.VerificationCodes.list(userEmail);

I have tried many different syntaxes, and either (a) I am really barking up the wrong tree, and it just won't work, Or I am using the wrong syntax =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach isn't working because [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return anything for the assignment.

The answer here really depends on what you're trying to do. If you just want the first returned code, then this will work by simply accessing the array element.

`const code = AdminDirectory.VerificationCodes.list(id).items[0].verificationCode;`

See in this example, there are multiple verification codes for the same user, but you'd be ignoring all but one.

```js
// Mock AdminDirectory
const AdminDirectory = {
  VerificationCodes: {
    list: (userId) => {
      const codes = [{
        userId: 'user@example.com',
        verificationCode: 'code1',
      }, {
        userId: 'user@example.com',
        verificationCode: 'code2',
      }];
      return { items: codes.filter(c => c.userId === userId) };
    },
  }
};

// Get the first code
const code = AdminDirectory.VerificationCodes
  .list('user@example.com')
  .items[0]
  .verificationCode;

console.log(code); // code1
```

I don't know the behavior of that API, but given that it can return multiple codes, you may want to be more selective and use something like [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: Thanks! this syntax works! And gives me what I am looking for.

Comment: Ok, the above snippet worked. But, now I have another related, unforeseen problem. That is, I am trying to get the code, and put it into an email template, to send it to new employees. The problem is, if I try to use it on a user that has not been created yet, it gives me problems. Almost all scenarios, I keep getting an Error Message: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. if I set the user to be someone I know already exists, it works fine. But, there seems to be some issue when executing my script, and then calling the API for the code. Any suggestions?

Comment: @drexlspivey This is a different question, it would be best if you posted this as a new question (and accepted this answer in the process!)

Comment: @drexlspivey You asked for a solution that would get and save the value all in one statement, but that comes at this cost of not being able to carry out all checks that can prevent errors like the one you're facing. Check out my response to your newer question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65992312/