# Chicken and Egg situation with retrieve 8-digit codes from new created accounts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am refactoring a script that creates new user accounts on google script G-Suite API.

The script works fine, and prepared an email templates, with login credentials--all as expected.

I am not trying to retrieve 8-digit authentication code, and attach it to the email template, since we moved to required 2FA organisation wide.

The crux of the problem is, I can't naturally get the codes if the account has not been created. There seems to be some issue -- some type of delay, where I can't get the codes fast enough? Not entirely sure. I got some help on how to retrieve the codes with this simple variable declaration:

```
AdminDirectory.VerificationCodes.list('donald.duck@example.com').items[0].verificationCode;
```

As you can imagine, the problem is donald.duck is not yet a user =)

I am about to give up, and just create another script that send a followup email with the 8-digit codes.

Anyone familiar with this API, this problem?

I have tried setting all types of variables with the above declaration, and placing it at all places within the current script - even right after where the user is created:

```
user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert(result.user);
```

But, it always comes back with a "Error Message: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" error. Which I assume is because the user does not exist - yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

Verification codes need to be generated first for every created user. Since this is a script, you can use `AdminDirectory.VerificationCodes.generate` to do this before listing.

**Sample:**

```
function generateKeys() {
  AdminDirectory.VerificationCodes.generate("dummyemail@dummy.com");
  var keys = AdminDirectory.VerificationCodes.list("dummyemail@dummy.com").items[0].verificationCode;
  console.log(keys);
}
```

This should display a numeric key on the execution log instead of `undefined`.

### Reference:

[Generate Verification Codes](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/verificationCodes/generate)

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because the `items` array is empty. Before grabbing a value that is assumed to be there, first check if the element exists.

```js
// Mock AdminDirectory
const AdminDirectory = {
  VerificationCodes: {
    list: (userId) => {
      const codes = [{
        userId: 'user@example.com',
        verificationCode: 'code1',
      }, {
        userId: 'user@example.com',
        verificationCode: 'code2',
      }];
      return { items: codes.filter(c => c.userId === userId) };
    },
  }
};

const response = AdminDirectory.VerificationCodes.list('user1@example.com');

// Check if the `items` array has anything before accessing the value
const code = response.items.length > 0 ? response.items[0].verificationCode : null;

console.log(code); // null
```